# Deleting a property from an object is removing the property from another object having similar names

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two objects. One is the master data, another is a similar object but contains certain properties that I am using and is a subset of the master data. Please find below the two objects:

```
$scope.masterData = {

"StoresForOrgs": {
    "PPP0001188": ["007071","007073","007079"],
    "PPP0001189": ["007075","0070756","0070789"],
    "PPP0001190": ["007075","0070756","0070789", "00707893", "00707899"]
    }
}

$scope.masterDataForDisplay = {

    "StoresForOrgsDisplay": {


        }
}
```

If in my code I do

```
$scope.masterDataForDisplay =    $scope.masterData;
```

this is linking both the objects and if I change the masterDataForDisplay it is changing the masterData as well. Now I understand that comparing these two would create the same reference and this could be avoided by using then

try this

```
$scope.masterDataForDisplay = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.masterData));
```

but even when the code is not executed this is happening. Are the objects being initialized before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
$scope.masterDataForDisplay = angular.copy($scope.masterData);
```

instead of

```
$scope.masterDataForDisplay = $scope.masterData;
```

copy() : Creates a deep copy of source, which should be an object or an array. So they dont share the same reference